# Reemplazar un texto de una consulta por otro en PHP

Tags: php

Buenas que tal: Consulta que no logro resolver tengo este código que me escribe "Instock o Outofstock"

`<?php echo esc_html ($product->get_stock_status( )); ?>`

y necesito poder remplazar "Instock o Outofstock" por "en Stock" No hay Stock"

gracias por la colaboración

Comment: Ese "Instock" y "Outstock" ¿De donde vienen? ¿Tienes una conexión a una base de datos, un fichero JSON o XML?  ¿En donde haces el `$product->get_stock_status`? Es muy ambigua tu pregunta y con muy poca info.

Comment: Aún siendo muy ambigua, entiendo que `esc_html ($product->get_stock_status( ))` devuelve un string. ¿No? Rafael

Comment: Necestiamos ver el codigo, que devuelve ```get_stock_status```?

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación está [str_replace PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php). También puedes hacer condiciones.

```
if esc_html($product->get_stock_status()) === "Instock"
 echo "En Stock"
else
 echo "No hay stock"
```

```
$msg = esc_html ( $product->get_stock_status()) === "InStock" ? "En stock" : "No hay stock";
echo $msg;
```

Comment: Échale un ojo a str_replace también :)

Comment: Funcionó Perfecto la segunda opción. Gracias por la ayuda...